# jquery : popup window doesn't appear whole page

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-plugins

popup window working very well.

`.backdrop` appear half part :(

here is the css code

```
.backdrop
{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:#000;
    opacity: .0;
    filter:alpha(opacity=0);
    z-index:50;
    display:none;
}
```

image sample 
[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/sweetmaanu/qWFLC/

Comment: Need more information as to what the problem is

Comment: I don't see the problem, can you be more specific?  The lightbox is appearing exactly where I'd expect it to appear based on its positioning.  (Explicit width of 500px, explicit left position of 30%, etc.)

Comment: Looks fine in the fiddle, do you  mean that the backdrop only covers half the screen? If so: 1. which browser, 2. which half (vertical/horizontal)?

Comment: @WillP. just click 'Lightbox' then we can see black background  move scroll to right then we can realise it doesn't cove whole page :(

Comment: @DaveEveritt now you can see image with the question

Comment: Oh I see, my screen was just too big to cause scrollbars.  If the .backdrop div is just setting a background color, is there a reason why you can't just set the body's background color instead?

Comment: @WillP. I just need to cover whole page with `.backdrop` at the back of the lightbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to easily fix this by changing `position` from `absolute` to `fixed`.

You could also give it a very large pixel value rather than 100% for the height and width if you don't want to use `position: fixed;`, ie. `height: 99999px; width: 99999px;`, but this can cause other issues that will have to be addressed (such as scrollbar issues).